# Not understanding the output when Converting Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: c, input, output

I have following `C` program, that takes a temperature in **Fahrenheit** and convert in to **Celsius** value. But, every time I input a value it always gives me`0.00` as output. I'm not understanding where is the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
    float cel_out, fht_in;

    printf("Enter a temperature in farenheit: ");
    scanf("%f", &fht_in);
    cel_out = (fht_in - 32) * (5/9);
    printf("Temperature in celcious: %.2f", cel_out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change expression `(5/9)` to use at least one float i.e `(5/9.0)` or `(5.0/9.0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this euqation

```
cel_out = (fht_in - 32) * (5/9);
```

When you use `5/9` it is integer data type which results 0.  so

```
 cel_out = (fht_in - 32) * 0;
```

Results 0 only!

You need to use-

```
cel_out = (fht_in - 32) * (5.0f/9.0f);
```

here it is treated as float values and gives the actual result of `5/9`.

Comment: Though the question is marked as duplicate, but thanks for your help :)